# removing the name of a pandas dataframe index after appending a total row to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot-table

I have calculated a series of totals tips by day of a week and appended it to the bottom of `totalspt` dataframe.

I have set the `index.name` for the `totalspt` dataframe to None.

However while the dataframe is displaying the default 0,1,2,3 index it doesn't display the default empty cell in the top left directly above the index.

How could I make this cell empty in the dataframe?

[image]

```
   total_bill   tip sex smoker  day time  size   tip_pct
0       16.54  1.01   F      N  Sun    D     2  0.061884
1       12.54  1.40   F      N  Mon    D     2  0.111643
2       10.34  3.50   M      Y  Tue    L     4  0.338491
3       20.25  2.50   M      Y  Wed    D     2  0.123457
4       16.54  1.01   M      Y  Thu    D     1  0.061064
5       12.54  1.40   F      N  Fri    L     2  0.111643
6       10.34  3.50   F      Y  Sat    D     3  0.338491
7       23.25  2.10   M      Y  Sun    B     3  0.090323

pivot  =  tips.pivot_table('total_bill', index=['sex', 'size'],columns=['day'],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
print pivot
day         Fri    Mon    Sat    Sun    Thu    Tue    Wed
sex size
F   2     12.54  12.54   0.00  16.54   0.00   0.00   0.00
    3      0.00   0.00  10.34   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
M   1      0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  16.54   0.00   0.00
    2      0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  20.25
    3      0.00   0.00   0.00  23.25   0.00   0.00   0.00
    4      0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  10.34   0.00

totals_row  =  tips.pivot_table('total_bill',columns=['day'],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).astype('float')
totalpt  = pivot.reset_index('sex').reset_index('size')
totalpt.index.name = None
totalpt = totalpt[['Fri', 'Mon','Sat', 'Sun', 'Thu', 'Tue', 'Wed']]
totalpt = totalpt.append(totals_row)
print totalpt
**day**              Fri    Mon    Sat    Sun    Thu    Tue    Wed #problem text day 
0           12.54  12.54   0.00  16.54   0.00   0.00   0.00
1            0.00   0.00  10.34   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
2            0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  16.54   0.00   0.00
3            0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  20.25
4            0.00   0.00   0.00  23.25   0.00   0.00   0.00
5            0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  10.34   0.00
total_bill  12.54  12.54  10.34  39.79  16.54  10.34  20.25
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the columns' name.

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2

In [13]: df.columns.name = 'XX'

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
XX  A  B
0   1  2
```

You can set it to None to clear it.

```
In [15]: df.columns.name = None

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   A  B
0  1  2
```

---

An alternative, if you wanted to keep it, is to give the index a name:

```
In [21]: df.columns.name = "XX"

In [22]: df.index.name = "index"

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
XX     A  B
index
0      1  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename_axis`. Since `0.17.0`

```
In [3939]: df
Out[3939]:
XX  A  B
0   1  2

In [3940]: df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
Out[3940]:
   A  B
0  1  2

In [3942]: df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

In [3943]: df
Out[3943]:
   A  B
0  1  2
```