# First row to header with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, header

I have the following pandas dataframe `df` :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = '''\
"Unnamed: 0","Unnamed: 1"   
Objet,"Unités vendues"  
Chaise,3
Table,2
Tabouret,1
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

which looks as:

```
  Unnamed: 0     Unnamed: 1
0      Objet  Unités vendues
1     Chaise                 3
2      Table                 2
3   Tabouret                 1
```

My target is to make the first row as header.

I use :

```
headers = df.iloc[0]
df.columns = [headers]
```

However, the "0" appears in index column name (which is normal, because this 0 was in the first row).

```
0          Objet Unités vendues 
1         Chaise              3 
2          Table              2
```

I tried to delete it in many way, but nothing work :

Neither `del df.index.name` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765548/remove-index-name-in-pandas)

Neither `df.columns.name = None` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834785/removing-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe-index-after-appending-a-total-row-to-a-d) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738129/how-to-remove-the-index-name-in-pandas-dataframe) (which is the same situation)

How can I have this expected output :

```
           Objet Unités vendues 
1         Chaise              3 
2          Table              2
```

Comment: `df = df.rename_axis(None)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765548/remove-index-name-in-pandas this might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about defining that when you load your table in the first place?

`pd.read_csv('filename', header = 1)`

otherwise I guess you can just do this:

`df.drop('0', axis = 1)`

Comment: When you have the names in a separate file or array, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me.

Replace:

```
    headers = df.iloc[0]
    df.columns = [headers]
```

with:

```
    headers = df.iloc[0].values
    df.columns = headers
    df.drop(index=0, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Using .values returns the values from the row Series as a list which does not include the index value.
Reassigning the column headers then works as expected, without the 0.
Row 0 still exists so it should be removed with df.drop.

Answer (score 1):

Having my data in U and my column names in Un I came up with this algorithm.
If you can shorten it, please do so.

```
U = pd.read_csv('U.csv', header = None) #.to_numpy()
Un = pd.read_csv('namesU.csv', header=None).T # Read your names csv, in my case they are in one column
Un = Un.append(U) # append the data U to the names
Un.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True) # reset the index and drop the old one, so you don't have duplicated indices
Un.columns = [Un.iloc[0]] # take the names from the first row
Un.drop(index=0, inplace=True) # drop the first row
Un.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True) # Return the index counter to start from 0
```

Another option:

```
Un = pd.read_csv('namesY.csv', header=None) # Read your names csv, in my case they are in one column
Un = list( Un[0] ) 
Un = pd.DataFrame(U, columns=[Un])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `skiprows` parameter did the job for me: i.e. `skiprows=N`
where `N` = the number of rows to skip (in the above example, 1), so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', skiprows=1)
```